# how to download selected folders & files into a single zip in asp.net mvc using angularjs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, c#-4.0

Scenario:-
I am in need to download files that user checkmarked to a single zip 
**INCLUDING PARENT FOLDER**

I have tried with more than 2-3 but every time I get different errors
Sometime

1. net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
2. Bad Directory
3. No Error but file is not downloaded

```
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.zip");

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.None;
    zip.AddSelectedFiles(Server.MapPath("~/content/audio/"+fileName));
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}

Response.Close();
```

> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/577929/Howplustopluszipplusaplusfolderplusandplusplusdown
>
> http://www.mindstick.com/blog/439/File%20download%20in%20zip%20Folder%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%204#.Vdtnbfmqqko

I am using

## filesaver to save the file

but nothing happens

Can someone tell how can I download the files into a zip file

### **Including Parent Folder**

**via ajax
using angularjs** not on page reload

I am using ASP.Net MVC